# Best way to optimization for my game ? (4 device Profiler)

Tags: optimization, mobile, unity-game-engine, profiling

i am developing my new 3d game. My game is infinite racing. i am instantiating objects. my game have character running animations,and waypoint code.Models are low poly but it is lagging (ipad3,Asus tablet,htc one m9) . working good some devices (general mobile discovery 2,iPhone 6,samsung s6)

What is my problem ? What can i do for optimizing?

my device profilers (ipad3,Asus tablet,htc one m9,iPhone 6)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: First thing to consider: rather than instantiating everything, consider using [object pooling](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/object-pooling) if you're frequently creating/destroying objects. Can't really suggest anything else, there are far too many reasons why performance might be poor - and it doesn't help that your various tests highlight different areas as problems. Without your code/scene setup, this will just lead to a frustrating guessing game.

Comment: but all instantiate objects have lots of character and their animations.is it problem for? object pooling

Comment: You can craft your object pooling mechanism to be almost exactly like the `Instantiate()` method, so no, as long as you design it properly there should be no real problems. Try it out!